# Как проверить, являются ли прямые скрещивающимися? (N-мерное пространство)

Tags: алгоритм, математика, геометрия, вычислительная-геометрия

Есть два отрезка в **N-мерном пространстве** (N < 50), каждый из которых задан двумя точками - началом и концом отрезка. Точки заданы координатами.

Необходимо определить, являются ли прямые, на которых лежат отрезки, скрещивающимися или пересекающимися. Известно, что прямые не коллинеарны.

Вариант решения:

Найти расстояние между прямыми. Если равно нулю - пересекающиеся, иначе - скрещивающиеся.

Но возникла проблема в нахождении расстояния между прямыми в **N-мерном пространстве**. Не сильно понятно, как это сделать.

Comment: Зачем искать расстояние? Непараллельные прямые являются пересекающимися если все четыре точки лежат в одной плоскости. В противном случае - скрещивающимися. Вот принадлежность одной плоскости и надо проверить.

Comment: @AnT, ну я же не против, можно и так. Но задача для меня легче не стала :)

Comment: https://otvet.mail.ru/question/73938326

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для `N = 3`:

Возьмите из четырех точек два раза по три (разные тройки, конечно) и посчитайте для двух векторов в каждой тройке точек векторное произведение. Если получившиеся вектора параллельны, четыре точки лежат в одной плоскости.

Для `N >= 3`:

Представим прямые в параметрическом виде.

первая - `x1 = a1 + b1 * u, x2 = a2 + b2 * u, ...`

вторая - `x1 = c1 + d1 * v, x2 = c2 + d2 * v, ...`

Приравняем выражения для соответствующих координат.

```
a1 + b1 * u = c1 + d1 * v
a2 + b2 * u = c2 + d2 * v
...
```

Получим N уравнений с двумя неизвестными.

Возьмем из этих уравнений любые два, решим. Если это решение подходит ко всем остальным уравнениям, прямые пересекаются.

Спасибо за внимание.